# Is there a way to change only the input text in the terminal of VS Code?

Tags: shell, terminal, customization, ansi-escape

I want to change the color of the text which I input into the terminal. For example, if I write `git status`, that whole line (including my alias + current repo) in my terminal should turn into this color of my choosing, say yellow.

The output, for example:

> On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean`

would still be printed in standard white.

I've checked https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#integrated-terminal-colors but to no success.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.foreground": "#ff0000"
```

},

in my **settings.json** applies to ALL text in the terminal, not only my input lines.

Comment: that is not VSC related it is configuring your shell prompt with ANSI Escape codes

Comment: (and interactive shell configuration is generally more on-topic at [unix.se] than here, unless you have a problem that you've done work to demonstrate/prove _only_ happens in VS Code and not in an interactive prompt)